# How to convert a numpy array to one hot encoding?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, one-hot-encoding

This is my dictionary and I have mapped inputs to numbers.

```
sex_dict = {
     "male" : 0,
     "female" : 1
}
type_dict = {
    "histo" : 0,
    "follow_up" : 1,
    "consensus" : 2,
    "confocal" : 3
}
localization_dict = {
    "back" : 0,
    "lower extremity" : 1,
    "trunk" : 2,
    "upper extremity" : 3,
    "abdomen" : 4
}
```

I will be taking input and need to convert it to one-hot encoding to serve it to my model. My plan is to convert the array of input (For Example: male, follow_up, trunk which is [0, 1, 2]) to a one hot encoding:

```
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

There should be 11 elements in the array however while converting I'm only able to get 9 elements due to 2 being the highest number in the array. How do I get the one-hot encoding to include all elements from the dictionary and end up with a (1,11) shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind going to pandas for data handling, you could use pd.Categorical along with pd.get_dummies to achieve the result. Here's a code snippet that should work for you:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

sex_list = [
  "male",
  "female"
]
type_list = [
  "histo",
  "follow_up",
  "consensus",
  "confocal"
]
localization_list = [
  "back",
  "lower extremity",
  "trunk",
  "upper extremity",
  "abdomen"
]

values = np.array([
  ["male", "follow_up", "trunk"]
])
values = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=["sex", "type", "localization"]).assign(
  sex=lambda row: pd.Categorical(row.sex, sex_list),
  type=lambda row: pd.Categorical(row.type, type_list),
  localization=lambda row: pd.Categorical(row.localization, localization_list)
)
encoded_array = pd.get_dummies(values).values
```

If you want to be particular about the number that is used to represent the different values, you can simply replace the different lists with the dicts. `sex_list -> sex_dict` and so on in the `pd.Categorical` calls.